# Message on each startup of Java after upgrade to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, java, 15.04

I just upgraded to 15.04 and noticed that on any Java program launched, the message

`Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar`

is printed to the console (which did not happen before the upgrade). Googling it only taught me what a Java Agent is. Now:

- Why does this message appear?
- Does anybody else observe this?
- Can it be disabled?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26249744/4464570

Comment: There is a bug filed against Ubuntu for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jayatana/+bug/1441487

Comment: If any of the following posts answered your question please accept that post as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 4):

This PPA is to get Unity AppMenu and HUD support for applications like NetBeans IDE, IntelliJ IDEA, Android Studio etc., as described [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/get-unity-global-menu-hud-support-for.html). So, unless you want this you can delete the package using `sudo apt-get remove jayatana` (and as the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26074446/picked-up-java-tool-options-javaagent-usr-share-java-jayatanaag-jar-when-st/26249744#26249744) thread suggests, removing `/usr/share/upstart/sessions/jayatana.conf` and restarting your computer). I am not sure if this is by default installed by 15.04 because it is not listed in the author's [repo](https://launchpad.net/~danjaredg/+archive/ubuntu/jayatana).

Answer (score 3):

> Why does this message appear?

Apparently it's reporting that the environment variable JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS has been set.

> Does anybody else observe this?

Yes, I see it and am annoyed by it as well.

> Can it be disabled?

A couple of sites suggest uninstalling jayatana, but I'm reluctant to do that since I don't really know why Ubuntu installed it in the most recent release.

Comment: That's exactly my knowledge and opinion on this so far, too. Please let me know if you find out anything more!

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to remove the message you can just edit your `$HOME/.bashrc` (if using bash) or `$HOME/.profile` and unset the variable with:

`unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`

This way jayatana will still be there and can just be enabled again if you remove the unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS from your `.bashrc` / `.profile`.

Note unsetting the variable is NOT equivalent to setting it to null. If you set it to null as follows you will still see a message when running any java based application:

`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=`

Comment: Using `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=` does not set to null but to the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of Jayatana, which is added to Ubuntu 15.04 in order to enable global menu for Java Swing applications. You can safely remove this message by entering the following command in a terminal. This command will remove the auto-start configuration of Jayatana.

```
sudo rm /usr/share/upstart/sessions/jayatana.conf
```

However, removing this option will disable the global menu support of Java Swing applications like Netbeans, IntelliJ IDEA. I have shared my workaround to suppress the message without losing the global menu in this article: [Global Menu Support for Java Applications](http://www.javahelps.com/2015/06/global-menu-support-for-java.html)